# Conflicts in Custom Code (HTML, CSS, Javascript) and Wordpress Theme

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, chatbot, wordpress-shortcode

I am working on integrating a Chatbot build in React.js, with a wordpress website. It's causing some conflicts with the Wordpress theme and not rendering correctly.

I've converted the React code into plain HTML, CSS, and Javascript and using the WP-Coder plugin, I created a block and added it into a new Wordpress project on a sample page, it worked fine. But when I try to add it into the main website which is built using Elementor, it shows weird behavior e.g., bad positioning of the chatbot icon, ugly styles that are not even applied etc. It's most probably because of some CSS/Javascript conflicts with Wordpress theme but I can't figure out the solution.

`[Codepen](https://codepen.io/aliwarraich/pen/gOZMObY)`